# start with 'a' and end with 'b' and 5-letter regex

Tags: regex

I want to start with 'a' and end with 'b' and make a five-letter regular expression.

example

```
afffb  o
abbbb  o
abbbbb x
axxb   x
a   b  o
a1!@b  o
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

`^a.{3}b$` will do the trick:

- `^` is the beginning of the string
- `a` is the literal character `a`
- `.{3}` is any character, three times (i.e., any three characters, not the necessarily the same character three times)
- `b` is the literal character `b`
- `$` is the end of the string